# C Makefile for a source tree

Tags: c, makefile, directory-structure

Need help in writing a Makefile for below source tree.
I have tried out simple examples for Makefile and those worked fine. But not able to figure out how do I write a Makefile for below kind of source tree.

I am organizing my code as below

```
root_dir:

    Makefile

    component1:
        dir1:
            file1.c file1.h 
        dir2:
            file2.c file2.h
        dir3:
            file3.c file3.h

    component2:
        dir4:
            file4.c file4.h
        dir5:
            file5.c file5.h

    common:
        debug.c debug.h
        utils.c utils.h
        main.c main.h
```

Here, main.c uses some functions declared in debug.h, utils.h, file1.h and file4.h. These file1.c and file4.c use the debug.h and utils.h. I have started writing the Makefile rules as below.

```
CC=gcc
CFlags=-c -g3 -Wall

myexec: main.o
        $(CC) main.o -o myexec

main.o: common/main.c common/main.h common/utils.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) common/main.c
```

This Makefile gives "undefined reference" error messages for the functions declared in utils.h. It can crib about the functions declared in debug.h, file1.h or file4.h, but shouldn't have given the error message for functions from utils.h

Please help me in finding out what is wrong with the Makefile here.

Comment: `make` isn't the one giving you the undefined reference error; it's `gcc`. Where do you _define_ the functions in `utils.h`?

Comment: All definitions are there in the respective .c files. The functions gcc is giving error for are defined in utils.c and are declared in utils.h for use by other files.

Comment: Your makefile only compiles `common/main.c`; you're not compiling `utils.c` anywhere.

Comment: Please suggest, how the Makefile should look like in this case.

Comment: Add a rule to build `util.c` (and every other .c file you need) and link it in the resulting `.o` file in your `myexec` rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's fix the `main.o` rule:

```
main.o: common/main.c common/main.h common/utils.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) common/main.c
```

If, as you say `main.c uses some functions declared in debug.h, utils.h, file1.h and file4.h`, then those headers should be prerequisites of the rule (so that if you modify a header, Make will rebuild `main.o`):

```
main.o: common/main.c common/main.h common/debug.h common/utils.h component1/dir1/file1.h component2/dir4/file4.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) common/main.c
```

Now look at the `myexec` rule:

```
myexec: main.o
    $(CC) main.o -o myexec
```

It's no surprise that you get "undefined reference" errors; the functions *declared* in `debug.h`, `utils.h`, `file1.h` and `file4.h` are *defined* in (I presume) `debug.c`, `utils.c`, `file1.c` and `file4.c`, which this makefile never mentions. **Do not proceed until you understand this.**

The way to handle this is tho have the `myexec` rule link all of the relevant object files:

```
myexec: main.o debug.o utils.o file1.o file4.o
    $(CC) main.o debug.o utils.o file1.o file4.o -o myexec
```

Naturally you must have rules for `debug.o`, `utils.o`, `file1.o` and `file4.o`, similar to the one for `main.o`.

Once that is done, you have a makefile that works but is needlessly long and redundant. "Effective but crude". It can be made much shorter and more elegant, but this answer is getting long; just get it working, then we can work on making it cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Beta. I was doing things wrong with the target's dependencies. Was able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

here is a long example:  it is for a linux embedded system, but will work with only minor changes for your application

These two makefiles will create an executable in each sub directory

it has a directory tree something like the following:

```
top
    utility .h and .c files
    makefile.top
    makefile.bot
    /executable1
        exec1 .h and .c files
    /executable2
        exec2 .h and .c files
```

contents of makefile.mak

```
SHELL = /bin/sh


#  note: this makefile.mak needs to be run from the ./src directory
# of the GOT4 directory tree


SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)


MAKE    :=  /usr/bin/make

CC      :=  /usr/bin/gcc

CP      :=  cp

MV      :=  mv

LDFLAGS :=  -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/lib

DEBUG   :=  -ggdb3

CCFLAGS :=  $(DEBUG) -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

#CPPFLAGS += =MD

LIBS    :=  -lssl -ldl -lrt -lz -lc -lm



.PHONY: AllDirectories


AllDirectories :=  \
    executable1 \
    executable2 



.PHONY: all

all: $(OBJ) $(AllDirectories)
    $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f ../makefile.bot name=Tsk_$d all ); )



#
# create dependancy files
#
%.d: %.c
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========



#
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
#
%.o: %.c %.d 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I. 
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    # 



.PHONY: clean
#clean: $(AllDirectories)
#   # ========== start clean activities ==========
#   rm -f *.o
#   rm -f $(name).map
#   rm -f $(name)
#   rm -f *.d
#   $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
#    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f makefile.mak clean ); )
#   # ========== end clean activities ==========

clean: $(AllDirectories)
    # ========== start clean activities ==========
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(name).map
    rm -f $(name)
    rm -f *.d
    rm -f ../bin/Tsk_*
    $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f ../makefile.bot name=Tsk_$d clean ); )
    # ========== end clean activities ==========



.PHONY: install
#install: $(AllDirectories)
#   # ========== start install activities ==========
#   $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
#    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f makefile.mak clean ); )
#   # ========== end install activities ==========

install: $(AllDirectories)
    # ========== start install activities ==========
    $(foreach d,$(AllDirectories), \
    ( cd $d && $(MAKE) -f ../makefile.bot name=Tsk_$d install ); )
    # ========== end install activities ==========



# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependancies for that file 
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif
```

and the makefile.bot

```
SHELL = /bin/sh


BINDIR  :=  /home/user/bin


.PHONY: all
all : $(BINDIR)/$(name) ../makefile.mak ../makefile.bot


#
# macro of all *.c files 
# (NOTE:
# (the following 'wildcard' will pick up ALL .c files
# (like FileHeader.c and FunctionHeader.c 
# (which should not be part of the build
# (so be sure no unwanted .c files in directory
# (or change the extension
#
SRC := $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.c=.d)
INC := $(SRC:.c=.h)


COMMON_OBJ := $(wildcard ../*.o)
#COMMON_SRC := $(wildcard ../*.c)
#COMMON_OBJ := $(COMMON_SRC:.c=.o)
#COMMON_DEP := $(COMMON_SRC:.c=.d)
#COMMON_INC := $(COMMON_SRC:.c=.h)

MAKE    :=  /usr/bin/make

CC      :=  /usr/bin/gcc

CP      :=  cp

MV      := mv

LDFLAGS :=  -L/usr/local/lib

DEBUG   :=  -ggdb3

CCFLAGS :=  $(DEBUG) -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99

#CPPFLAGS += =MD

LIBS    :=   -lssl -ldl -lrt -lz -lc -lm



#
# link the .o files into the executable 
# using the linker flags
# -- explicit rule
#
$(name): $(OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ) ../makefile.mak ../makefile.bot
    #
    # ======= $(name) Link Start =========
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(COMMON_OBJ) $(LIBS)
    # ======= $(name) Link Done ==========
    #



# note:
# using MV rather than CP results in all executables being re-made everytime
$(BINDIR)/$(name): $(name)
    #
    # ======= $(name) Copy Start =========
    sudo $(CP) $(name) $(BINDIR)/.
    # ======= $(name) Copy Done ==========
    #



#
#create dependancy files -- inference rule
# list makefile.mak as dependancy so changing makfile forces rebuild
#
%.d: %.c 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) -M $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$;                      \
    sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@;     \
    rm -f $@.$$$$
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========



# 
# compile the .c file into .o files using the compiler flags
# -- inference rule
#
%.o: %.c %.d 
    # 
    # ========= START $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -I. 
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
    # 



.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    # ========== CLEANING UP ==========
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f $(name).map
    rm -f $(name)
    rm -f *.d
    # ========== DONE ==========



.PHONY: install
install: all

# include the contents of all the .d files
# note: the .d files contain:
# <filename>.o:<filename>.c plus all the dependancies for that .c file 
# I.E. the #include'd header files
# wrap with ifneg... so will not rebuild *.d files when goal is 'clean'
#
ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif
```